# Angular Routing - Compile Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a bug in my angular app, that I fixed the improper way. So it's not a pressing issue. Just want to know why, so I clean my code

I have a class that holds my route configuration, and some functions to query a route, to fill a route parameter, to get my routes, ...

All my functions and attributes are static.

```
static _routes: { [key: string]: Route } = {
    'home' : { path : '', redirectTo : 'client', pathMatch : 'full' },
    'client' : { path : 'client', component : ClientComponent },
    'mandats' : { path : 'mandats', component : MandatsComponent }
};

static route_a: Routes = [
    { path : '', redirectTo : 'client', pathMatch : 'full' },
    { path : 'client', component : ClientComponent },
    { path : 'mandats', component : MandatsComponent }
];

static routes(): Routes {
    return Object.values( AppRoutes._routes );
}

static route( name: string ): Route {
    return AppRoutes._routes[ name ] ? AppRoutes._routes[ name ] : null;
}

static routeUrl( name: string, args: object ): string {
    const route = Object.assign( {}, AppRoutes.route( name ) );
    Object.keys( args ).forEach( key => route.path.replace( `:${key}`, args[ key ] ) );
    return route.path;
}
```

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plnxc.png)

The problem is : When I use my routes() function, I get a [compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT6V7.png)
I don't understand why, I now use the property route_a holding my routes and that works while both method return the same content.

**What I tried:**

- My _routes property was private, I tried by setting it public
- Setting my function as a getter
- log the result of the function -> expected result : array of object

Thanks anyone who can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you linked to refers to `loadChildren`, so I assume you're using Ahead-of-time compilation. In this mode, the compiler's ability is limited in some ways. It needs to be able to analyze the routes statically, so using the result of a `routes()` function -- rather than the statically defined `routes_a` object -- can confuse it.

Check whether running Just-in-Time compilation works. If so, I suspect this is the problem you're facing. Take a look at [this reference](https://github.com/UltimateAngular/aot-loader/wiki/Limitations-with-AoT) for more examples of the AOT compiler's limitations. Don't forget to let us know what you find out so we can learn from your xp.